# Understanding and slightly modifying this script?

Tags: autohotkey

The script below Detects any newly created window. It works really well. Thing is I need to detect when the `Save As`, `Open file` , `Import` dialogs are created.

The script does not detect them because they are classes belonging to the process that created them. Is there any way to modify it so it detects these dialog boxes too?  Thank you.

```
#Persistent
Gui +LastFound
hWnd := WinExist()

DllCall( "RegisterShellHookWindow", UInt,hWnd )
MsgNum := DllCall( "RegisterWindowMessage", Str,"SHELLHOOK" )
OnMessage( MsgNum, "ShellMessage" )
Return

ShellMessage( wParam,lParam ) {
  Local k
  If ( wParam = 1 ) ;  HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED := 1
     {
       NewID := lParam
       SetTimer, MsgBox, -1
     }
}

MsgBox:
 WinGetTitle, Title, ahk_id %NewID%
 WinGetClass, Class, ahk_id %NewID%
 TrayTip, New Window Opened, Title:`t%Title%`nClass:`t%Class%
Return
```

Comment: You can use the API function ["IsWindowVisible"](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/DllCall.htm#ExIsWindowVisible) in a timer to detect whenever a dialog window becomes visible.

Comment: @user3419297 I actually found another means. Good old hotkey was actually the way to go about it, I`ll keep your suggestion in mind though. Thank y/u